# How can I set a Perl script to run automatically when my Win 11 computer restarts?

Tags: windows, service, startup

I would like my computer to automatically start running a Perl script when my Win 11 computer starts/restarts. Don't know if I can make that a "service" but all the search results for creating services in Win 11 point to NT services. And I couldn't find a way to make it a Startup tool.

It would also be great if I could see it running in a popup cmd.exe window or some such.

-- added --
I can put a shortcut in the Startup folder but that only works following a login. I want it to start before login.

-- end --

Any thoughts?